# How to Use Third Part Libraries like Vue3GoogleMap with Vue3 CDN Only

Tags: google-maps, vuejs3, cdn

I am trying to implement a google map in a WordPress website through Vue3 Cdn. Following is my code:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue3-google-map"></script>


        <div id="app">
            <div>
                {{ message }}
                <GoogleMap api-key="<API_KEY_HERE>" style="width: 100%; height: 500px" :center="center" :zoom="15">
                    <Marker :options="{ position: center }" />
                </GoogleMap>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            const {
                createApp
            } = Vue
            const {
                GoogleMap
            } = Vue3GoogleMap
            const {
                Marker
            } = Vue3GoogleMap
            createApp({
                data() {
                    return {
                        message: 'Hello Vue!'
                    }
                },
                components: {
                    GoogleMap,
                    Marker
                },
            }).mount('#app')
        </script>
```

I am unable to figure out how to use third party packages like `vue3-google-map` in this case where libraries are imported through CDN in the website. Please guide. Thanks

Comment: When you import it, you bind it to `window` and call it in a somewhat similar approach like you would do with an NPM package. I recommend console logging the object to try to found out the exact methods you will need to call.

Comment: @kissu Can you please explain more how can I do that in code? Thanks

Comment: If you read some of the code of the CDN, you'll notice a `window.google.maps`. So I guess that you could start inspecting that one first, to see if it's properly loaded etc.